# emit Transfer error: data out-of-bounds on Remix

Tags: contract-development, remix

Newbe here. I am testing a smart contract on Remix. When I try to burn ERC20 tokens by sending them to the 0 address I get the following error

> transact to Ex.transfer errored: Error: data out-of-bounds (length=64,
> offset=96, code=BUFFER_OVERRUN, version=abi/5.0.7)

Here the line of code that causes it (if I comment this out, there is no error):

```
emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), amount);
```

amount is uint256. Am I doing anything wrong? Are the arguments wrong? I have seen the exact same code on smart contracts that have been deployed and are running fine.

Remix settings:

Compiler version: tried 0.7.0 and 0.8.3

EVM version: tried compiler default and istanbul

environment: tried JavaScript VM and ganache local provider. With JS I get said error, with ganache I don't get the error message in Remix but the transaction stays pending in Remix

In case I haven't provided all necessary information I apologize. Please let me know if you need additional information.

Edit:

Minimum example to reproduce the error:

```
function testEmit(uint256 amount) public  {
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, address(0), amount);
    }
```

Comment: I tried with a function emitting just Transfer event and it works as expected, using solc v0.8.1. The contract has to be doing something else.

Comment: i added the minimum example that reproduces the error on Remix - any ideas?

Comment: How is Transfer event declared? I use openzeppelin's ERC20 contract for the definition. I've tested with the same function and it works.

Comment: Same problem here with 0 address passed to a Transfer event, did you find out why?